# Compare versions of the same package in different repositories (i.e. stable vs backports) using apt-cache show

Tags: debian, apt, backports

I'm trying to find out the version of a particular package available in the backports repo to compare it with the version available in the stable repo.

But when I give

```
apt-cache show <package> | grep Version
```

I always get the same result as with

```
apt-cache -t wheezy-backports show <package> | grep Version
```

This seems to be the case no matter the package I'm searching.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-cache show` shows information for all versions of a package.

```
$ apt-cache show 0ad | grep Version:
Version: 0.0.14-3~bpo70+2
Version: 0~r11863-2
```

`apt-cache policy` presents the information you want in a more compact form, and includes the corresponding repository origin.

```
$ apt-cache policy 0ad             
0ad:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0~r11863-2
  Version table:
     0.0.14-3~bpo70+2 0
        100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports/main amd64 Packages
     0~r11863-2 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
```

You get nicer, easier-to-parse output from [`apt-show-versions`](http://packages.debian.org/apt-show-versions) (as already mentioned [by bersch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121345)), which isn't installed by default.

```
$ apt-show-versions -a 0ad
Not installed
0ad 0~r11863-2       wheezy           ftp.debian.org
0ad 0.0.14-3~bpo70+2 wheezy-backports ftp.debian.org
No stable-updates version
0ad not installed
```

Answer (score 0):

My `apt-cache` does not have `-t` switch, so I use `apt-show-versions`

```
$ apt-show-versions bash
bash:i386 4.1-3 install ok installed
bash:i386 4.1-3      squeeze ftp.de.debian.org
bash:i386 4.2+dfsg-1 testing ftp.de.debian.org
bash:i386 4.3-2      testing ftp.de.debian.org
```